# How to select a entire row in primeng table

Tags: angular, primeng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CACVE.png)>  <p-table #dt [value]="configDetails" [loading]="loadingconfigDetails"
[alwaysShowPaginator]="false" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true" [responsive]="true"
[(selection)]="selectedValues">

> Highlight the selected row based on selection

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pSelectableRow]="rowData"
and you can use click event: onRowSelect()
Code Example:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedCar">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```